# How to set a local variable equal to a user's specific comment in a post? probably very simple

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show near the top of my view the user's comment for that post, if they have made a comment at all. So in my Comment controller I want to initialize the variable @user_comment to the comment object of that specific user for that specific post. I understand this isn't the most complex of questions.

Here's what I have so far:

**Relevant Comment Controller**

```
def show
        @comments = Comment.find(params[:id])   
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @user = current_user.id
        @user_comment = Comment.where(post_id: @post, user_id: @user)
        #@user_comment is the local variable im trying to set to the user's comment for that specific post.
end
```

**Relevant Schema**

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
```

**Show Page**

```
<% if @user_comment.nil?  || !user_signed_in? %>
    <!-- Normal comment form -->            
<% else %>
    <!-- I want to show the user's comment here, I tried something along the lines of @user_comment.content, but it says it's not a valid method, which gives me the idea I didn't initialize it properly. -->      
<% end %>
```

And if you all know a great resource that teaches querying well, I'd love to look it over because obviously this is something I'd need to know moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that seems a bit confusing is that you want to render the 'post' on the comment show page. What seems more logical would be to render the 'comment' on the post show page.

**Post Controller**

```
def show
  @post    = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @post.comments.where(user_id: current_user) # This uses an association
end
```

**Post Show Page**

```
<% if @comment.nil?  || !user_signed_in? %> <!-- Here I use the @comment variable -->
  <!-- Normal comment form -->            
<% else %>
  <!-- I want to show the user's comment here, I tried something along the lines of @user_comment.content, but it says it's not a valid method, which gives me the idea I didn't initialize it properly. -->      
<% end %>
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments # This creates the association to grab the comments
end
```

---

**Your Code**

In the comments controller, you have this:

```
@comments = Comment.find(params[:id])   
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

The post and the comment likely won't have the same `id`. And seeing as it is the comments controller, the `id` that gets passed through params will be the `id` of the comment. So if you *were* to do everything through the comments controller, you would want to use an association like `@post = @comment.post`. I changed `@comments` to `@comment` and used an association. The comment model would need `belongs_to :post` in order to make the association work.

Comment: thanks a lot. I understand now. Just to add, I had to loop through @comment in the show to be able to post just the one comment's content. Why would that be? I'm not complaining, it works fine. Just wondering.

Comment: When using .where it will return a set, even if there is only one result. So you will need to do .first or do a loop.  If you are using a has_many relationship, your code should be able to accomodate if the user has more than one comment.  If you want to only allow one comment, then use a has_one relationship.

Comment: I mostly agree with Kevin here. I should have put `.where.first` because this will always return a collection of 1. I'm not clear on the expected behavior using `has_one` instead of `has_many` because even if it were to work, it would always require the `where` statement every time. Therefore, if you wanted to get all of the comments and display them farther down on the post show page, then you couldn't use the `has_one` association and would need a `has_many` anyways.